# Use firebase cloud function to send POST request to non-google service

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

When I try to make a post request to my firebase function I get this error:
getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)

Probably error occurred because I have free Spark plan. I would like to know if Flame plan is enough or I need to select Blaze plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce abuse your project needs to be on a paid plan to be able to make calls to non-Google services from Cloud Functions. It doesn't matter whether that is the Blaze (pay as you go) or Flame (fixed price) plan.

On the Blaze plan: If you stay within the free quota, you still won't pay anything.

Answer (score 0):

Is the POST request being made in the Firebase Function? If so, the Flame plan should be enough as long as you're using less than 5GB/month. Refer to https://firebase.google.com/pricing/ for more details on that.

Comment: yeah, basically I send data to firebase function and from there I use that data to make a user on mangopay (service for payments) with help of their API.

Comment: Yup, in that case Flame should be fine for non-Google services. If you need more than 5GB/month you can upgrade to Blaze